# Random svn errors during update

Tags: svn

We have developped a java application (on Windows) that connect to a remote SVN repository to synchronize the local data, on demand.
We use the following tigris components:

- svnclientadapter-1.8.0.jar
- svnjavahl-1.7.4.jar

The SVN repository is accessed via HTTPS.

The application sometimes fails during the update of the local repository (using the function "update") with the error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/Etimlite_repository/!svn/me': Could not read response body: SSL error: wrong version number

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/Etimlite_repository/!svn/me': Could not read response body: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/Etimlite_repository/!svn/me': Could not read status line: SSL error: wrong version number
```

As the application performs retries (after 3 retries, also performs a svncleanup), sometimes it continues correctly and sometimes we get the error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: REPORT of '/svn/Etimlite_repository/!svn/me': Could not read response body: SSL error: wrong version number

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Attempted to lock an already-locked dir
svn: Working copy 'C:\EtimLite\download\data\location' locked.
svn: 'C:\EtimLite\download\data\location' is already locked.
```

Can this issue be due to a network problem ? 
What is the right function to use to re-establish a good synchronization process ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update to the latest version SVN client and SVN server. Sometimes SVN does lock up due to network error due to being in the middle of operation and that is the reason of needing to do SVN clean up to release the lock.

Comment: This does not make sense. Upgrading the server and client won't fix problems that are caused by network problems.

Comment: A version mismatch between the client and server can cause the lockup as well. Ensure the client version supports the SVN server version.

Comment: Show some evidence. A client/server version mismatch should not cause intermittent network errors. With different versions, it should either work or throw a very explicit "incompatible versions" error.